# SQL count records depending on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which has account information for each individual working day. Each record shows the balance on the account for that particular day. I need to create a field that has a running count on how many days it has been since the balance on that particular account was zero.

For example: I have an account which is number 00000001. It was opened a week ago. The database has created a record for the account for last Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Monday. The account did not have a balance until Friday and the balance was the same for Monday. I want the field to show '2' as a result. Further to this if the balance drops to '0' today, I need the count to reset on the next record and start again if the account has a balance the following day. There are several accounts in this table so I need this to work for each one individually.

Below is as far as I have got:

```
SELECT
pos.EffDate,
cus.CNA1,
pos.ACNO,
pos.CCY,
pos.LDBL,
pos.LDBLUSD,
MIN(pos3.effdate) AS 'First Post Date',
pos3.Balcount

FROM[dbo].[Account] AS pos
JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS cus ON ((pos.CNUM=cus.CUST_NO) AND (cus.effdate=pos.effdate))
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pos2.effdate, pos2.ACNO, SUM(CASE pos2.LDBL WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'Balcount' FROM [dbo].[Account] AS pos2 GROUP BY pos2.ACNO, pos2.Effdate HAVING pos2.effdate BETWEEN pos2.effdate AND MIN(pos2.effdate)) pos3 ON pos3.ACNO = pos.ACNO
WHERE pos.effdate >='1 Dec 2015' AND pos.Effdate <'30 Dec 2015'
AND pos.srcsys = 'MP_UK'
AND pos.LDBL <= 0
AND pos.CNUM <> '000020'
AND pos.intbear <> 'N'
AND pos.blockdeb IS null

GROUP BY pos.EffDate,cus.CNA1,pos.ACNO,pos.CCY,pos.LDBL,pos.LDBLUSD, pos3.Balcount
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

If you need me to clarify anything please let me know. All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I think you need to take a look a the lead and lag functions since your count criteria depend on the previous/ next row for the set

Comment: Just a side note ; I wouldn't suggest using column numbers for any clause, as you did with order by, for queries that are going to be used a lot. It is better to specify the actual columns in case the query changes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will have a look into lead and lag functions. The column numbers was when I order the data as an afterthought. I will change that to actual column names as you advised, thanks NullException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to group the data, based on the number of time the account is zero before a given row.  Then, within each group, you want to enumerate the records.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do these things with window functions.  I am not sure exactly what your sample query has to do with the question, but here is the basic idea:

```
select a.*, row_number() over (partition by cust_no, grp order by eff_date) as seqnum
from (select a.*,
             sum(case when balance = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over 
                 (partition by cust_no order by eff_date) as grp
      from Account a
     ) a;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do something very similar using `apply`.

Comment: Is there a reason for an anonymous downvote (which I'm pretty sure is unwarranted)?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will give this a try and let you know how it goes. Apologies if my original code confused things.

Comment: Just needed to make a few small tweaks and it worked an absolute charm. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. Really appreciate it and it's made a massive difference to me.